# How to convert to CSV to Keyed JSON?

Tags: python, json, csv, key

Currently, I'm creating to JSON with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\config_all_env.csv')
# print(data.to_string())
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# print(df)

json_file = df.to_json(orient='index',indent=4)
print(json_file)
```

my 'config_all_env.csv' looks like this

```
_key,index,source
123456789100:LogGroup1,index1,Account1-123456789100:LogGroup1
123456789100:LogGroup2,index1,Account1-123456789100:LogGroup2
678901234200:LogGroup3,index2,Account2-678901234200:LogGroup3
678901234200:LogGroup4,index2,Account2-678901234200:LogGroup4
```

And the Output is like this:

```
{
    "0":{
        "_key":"123456789100:LogGroup1",
        "index":"index1",
        "source":"Account1-123456789100:LogGroup1"
    },
    "1":{
        "_key":"123456789100:LogGroup2",
        "index":"index1",
        "source":"Account1-123456789100:LogGroup2"
    },
    "2":{
        "_key":"678901234200:LogGroup3",
        "index":"index2",
        "source":"Account2-678901234200:LogGroup3"
    },
    "3":{
        "_key":"678901234200:LogGroup4",
        "index":"index2",
        "source":"Account2-678901234200:LogGroup4"
    }
}
```

But, this website: https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm has an option of Keyed JSON, after parsing which this output is received:

```
{
   "123456789100:LogGroup1": {
      "index": "index1",
      "source": "Account1-123456789100:LogGroup1"
   },
   "123456789100:LogGroup2": {
      "index": "index1",
      "source": "Account1-123456789100:LogGroup2"
   },
   "678901234200:LogGroup3": {
      "index": "index2",
      "source": "Account2-678901234200:LogGroup3"
   },
   "678901234200:LogGroup4": {
      "index": "index2",
      "source": "Account2-678901234200:LogGroup4"
   }
}
```

How to Achieve this using Python, since its not feasible to open this website everytime and do the conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the "_key" column as the index to the pandas dataframe first, this should achieve what you want (if I've interpreted your problem correctly).

```
import pandas as pd

my_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    "0":{
        "_key":"123456789100:LogGroup1",
        "index":"index1",
        "source":"Account1-123456789100:LogGroup1"
    },
    "1":{
        "_key":"123456789100:LogGroup2",
        "index":"index1",
        "source":"Account1-123456789100:LogGroup2"
    },
    "2":{
        "_key":"678901234200:LogGroup3",
        "index":"index2",
        "source":"Account2-678901234200:LogGroup3"
    },
    "3":{
        "_key":"678901234200:LogGroup4",
        "index":"index2",
        "source":"Account2-678901234200:LogGroup4"
    }
}, orient="index")

my_dict = my_data.set_index("_key").to_json(orient='index',indent=4)
```

Output:

```
{
    "123456789100:LogGroup1":{
        "index":"index1",
        "source":"Account1-123456789100:LogGroup1"
    },
    "123456789100:LogGroup2":{
        "index":"index1",
        "source":"Account1-123456789100:LogGroup2"
    },
    "678901234200:LogGroup3":{
        "index":"index2",
        "source":"Account2-678901234200:LogGroup3"
    },
    "678901234200:LogGroup4":{
        "index":"index2",
        "source":"Account2-678901234200:LogGroup4"
    }
}
```